# Is it possible to design a decision tree through the visTree function

Tags: html, css, r, rpart, visnetwork

I am using the `rpart`  Decision Tree algorithm and would like to visualize it with an interactive visualization using the `visNetwork`  library.To visualize the Decision Tree model, I use the `visTree`  function from the `visNetwork` library. Specifically, I am interested in whether it is possible to change the background color and enlarge the graph display.Here is a code snippet from the visNetwork documentation:

```
library(rpart)
library(visNetwork)


data("solder")
res <- rpart(Opening~., data = solder, control = rpart.control(cp = 0.00005))
visTree(res, height = "800px", nodesPopSize = TRUE, minNodeSize = 10, 
        maxNodeSize = 30, width = "100%")
```

If it can't be done through function, can it be done through HTML and CSS?